# Get count of all commas in a each line from csv file

Tags: c#, console-application

What I'm trying to accomplish is to read CSV file and get the count of commas in each row. ALL CSV files are identical. Have 9 columns and they are separated by `(,)` So I wrote a simple function that reads the files and using `foreach` loop I read each line in the file.

```
public static void readCSVFile(string path)
   {
      string _path = path;

      string [] text = File.ReadAllLines(_path);

      foreach (string line in text)
      {
          string currentLine = line;
          Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);
      }

   }
```

So typically `currentLine` will have an output like this:

> number , 10/21/14 07:01:10, 00:28:29, number (name), number; number (name), number, number (name), N/A, number

There're total of eight `,` in the line. How can I programmatically get the total number of `commas` in each line, so I can do something like this in my `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (string line in text)
{
   string currentLine = line;

   if (totalNumberOfCommas == 8)
   {
        //do something
   }
   else
   {
        //do something else
   }
```

Comment: why not split the lines read and work with the *data* rather than the separators? you can count the number of resulting elements if you need to

Comment: `line.Count(c => c == ',')`

Comment: Which is the character that is used to divide the columns of each line? You know, CSV stands for "Comma Separated Values File"

Comment: @Plutonix, I'm not doing any work with that CSV file. The only reason I want to do this is to make sure each line contains exactly 8 commas. If it contains more or less then the job that generates the CSV file did not do it correctly.

Comment: What if your data contains commas?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen is too easy to make sense of, try this instead... `int commaCount = currentline.Length - string.Join(string.Empty, currentline.Split(',')).Length;`

Comment: @Steve, I do know what CSV stands for. `,` is used to separate each column.

Comment: I see your comment now, you are not sure that you have 9 columns, but the question doesn't explain this instead you say: _ALL CSV files are identical. Have 9 columns and they are separated by comma_

Comment: @Steve, sorry for not clarifying. It's `9` columns but `8` commas. The last column does not contain comma.

Comment: do you want to discard the lines that don't have 8 commas?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen, if you write your comment as an answer, I will accept that as answer, since you were the first one suggesting that solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just want to count the commas, you can take advantage of the fact that string implements `IEnumerable<char>`, so you can use `Count` like this:

```
var commas = line.Count(c => c == ',');
```

Comment: +1 And this has less overhead than splitting the line into an array of strings.

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen, perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use the String.Split functionality.

```
foreach (string line in text)
{
   string currentLine = line;

   string[] eachColumn = currentLine.Split(',');

   if (eachColumn.Length == 9)
   {
        //do something
   }
   else
   {
        //do something else
   }
}
```

Note that this will not work properly if you have commas in your actual data (not as a field separator).  You should probably look into a csv parser to help with this sort of thing.

Comment: that's exactly what I want to check. To make sure there's no extra commas in that fields.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```
foreach (string line in text)
{
   string currentLine = line;
   int totalNumberOfCommas = currentLine.Split(',').Length - 1;

   if (totalNumberOfCommas == 8)
   {
        //do something
   }
   else
   {
        //do something else
   }
}
```