# How to count semicolon for each line of an csv file in c#

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I make an console app, this app is reading csv files using linq to load every line of the file into an IEnumerable.

```
var lines = from rawLine in File.ReadLines(readFolderFile, Encoding.Default) where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawLine) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawLine.Trim(';')) select rawLine;
```

Now I need to check how many semicolon every line compared to the first line has and if a line has more semicolon than the first one it will be added to an errorList.

So my question is there any easy way to just count the amount of an specific symbol per line?

The outcome should be that I can say, after my source file is proceed with this app, that every row has the identical amount of columns.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Perhaps you should find a library that can handle *jagged* files instead? Or reject faulty lines?

Comment: `var colAmount = lines.Count(c => c == ";");` but so far im still searching what is there. I would like to use linq for this, but if that is not possible well... First I really just need to know how do I identify a specific symbol to count it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
int count = source.Count(f => f == ';');
```

where source is string variable.

So in your case it will look like:

```
foreach (var line in lines)
{
  if (line.Count(f => f == ';') != firstLineCount))
  {
    //your logic here
  }
}
```

Comment: I found something like this before here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513635/get-count-of-all-commas-in-a-each-line-from-csv-file) but it doesnt work for me. I get the error that I cant use == on strings or chars. That is how I used it so far: `var colAmount = lines.Count(c => c == ';');`

Comment: Okay thanks I just added `var firstLineCount= lines.First().Count(f => f == ';');` and it works like a charm

Answer (score 4):

Remember every string could be treated as `IEnumerable<char>` so:

```
using System.Linq;
...
"my;string;from;csv;file".Count(c => c.Equals(';')); // = 4;
...
```